# React - Realm result as list of object

Tags: reactjs, list, react-native, realm

I want to add a property to result query of realm and i did something like this

```
findAllSelected() {
    let result = super.findAll()
    result = result.map(item => {
        return {...item, isSelected: false}
    })
    return result
}
```

This is my findAll method

```
findAll () {
   return RealmSchemas.objects(this.schema)
}
```

But later i found it the result from findAll is looks like this

> {"0": {"contact_id": 7, "id": 1, "isArchived": false, "isPinned":
> true, "message": Test 1", "name": "User 1", "time": "14.10 PM", "unread": 1}, "1":
> {"contact_id": 8, "id": 2, "isArchived": false, "isPinned": true,
> "message": "Test 2", "name": "User 2",
> "time": "11.21 AM", "unread": 2}}

My question is how do i add property to array likes that? Or other way around how do i convert result of my query to list of object so i can use map to add a property?

Answer (score 0):

You may try using this:

```
let result = super.findAll()
for (const propertyName in result){
   result[propertyName].isSelected = false
}
```

It gets all the property names in the object and adding a new property `isSelected` for each iteration.